# Как сделать чтобы echo бот отправлял картинки?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, echo

Начал изучать python, написал echo бота который отправляет текст, мне интересно как сделать так, чтобы он отправлял фото. Может с этим можно что-то придумать, но я что-то не понимаю
`bot.send_document(user_id,.....)`

Comment: вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем.

Уточните подробности, никто не умеет читать мысли.

Comment: Пример отправки фотки и группы фоток: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d13c485ff77619efdc2324d6d8af3c70b1342bb3/telegram_bot_examples/funs_tests__speak_pict_youtube/speak_pict_youtube.py#L55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из простых примеров эхо-фото-бота

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['photo'])
def echo_photo_bot(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, message.photo[0].file_id, message.caption)
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```